# How to stack button views to make a piano style keyboard?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I'm trying to make a piano style keyboard with buttons. I have put the bottom buttons (usually white on a piano) at one third height. Now I want to add the upper buttons (usually black on a piano). I want to achieve something like:

[image]

This my layout XML: https://drive.google.com/file/d/13sQNbnxCIjDqENbUY17gQStqzASnOwdJ/view

Comment: Question is too broad, Please focus on a specific issue you are facing. See [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I'm still begginer but the first thing which comes to my mind is that I don't know how to put LinearLayout on LinearLayout.

Comment: Please attempt to write the code and if there is any problem while coding we will be happy to help you. I think it is better to start by a simple tutorial and try to learn android using a course or a tutorial.

Comment: @Soroosh I watched about 8 of 30 hours course but not all things I need were covered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a good task for `ConstraintLayout`. With it, you can achieve a *flat* layout, where you have no nesting. The main concepts in the layout are constraints. You can read more about them at https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout.

In the `ConstraintLayout`, you organise the views around with constraints. That is, you can say that the white keys should all be constrained to the parent's bottom and their top to a guideline at 2/3 the screen height. Then you can say that the first button should be most to the start of the screen, next to the second button, which is next to the third button and so on. The layout will automatically evenly spread them out.

After that, you put the black keys on top. You can specify their width by using a percent value (percent of parent width, that is). At the end, you get something like this:

```
// Layout
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/topGuideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.67" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/blackKeysGuideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.85" />

    <!-- White buttons -->

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="@style/KeyboardKeyWhite"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/topGuideline" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        style="@style/KeyboardKeyWhite"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/button3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/button1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/topGuideline" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        style="@style/KeyboardKeyWhite"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/button4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/topGuideline" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        style="@style/KeyboardKeyWhite"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/button5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/button3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/topGuideline" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        style="@style/KeyboardKeyWhite"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/button6"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/button4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/topGuideline" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        style="@style/KeyboardKeyWhite"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/button7"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/button5"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/topGuideline" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        style="@style/KeyboardKeyWhite"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/button6"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/topGuideline" />

    <!-- Black buttons -->

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/blackButton1"
        style="@style/KeyboardKeyBlack"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/blackKeysGuideline"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/button1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/topGuideline" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/blackButton2"
        style="@style/KeyboardKeyBlack"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/blackKeysGuideline"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/button3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/topGuideline" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/blackButton3"
        style="@style/KeyboardKeyBlack"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/blackKeysGuideline"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/button5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/button4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/topGuideline" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/blackButton4"
        style="@style/KeyboardKeyBlack"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/blackKeysGuideline"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/button6"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/button5"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/topGuideline" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/blackButton5"
        style="@style/KeyboardKeyBlack"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/blackKeysGuideline"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/button7"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/button6"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/topGuideline" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

// Styles
<style name="KeyboardKeyWhite" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:layout_margin">2dp</item>
    </style>

<style name="KeyboardKeyBlack" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">2dp</item>
    <item name="layout_constraintWidth_percent">0.08</item>
</style>
```

[image: The end result]